# in pthread_create(), behavior when args is freed before the created thread exits

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

In `pthread_create( *thread, *attr, *start_routine, *arg)`, if `arg` is freed before the created thread exits, what is the behaviour?  I didn't see it described in the specification from Open Group, so it may very well be undefined, I just can't find a place to confirm either way.

Comment: The only one who *may* dereference `arg` is `start_routine`, provided by the caller. So `pthread_create` specification needn't bother about `arg` lifetime: it is up to `start_routine` implementation to garantee, that it doesn't dereference `arg` after free.

Comment: That's completely normal, in particular when the thread frees the data itself. For everything else, like dangling pointers, no special rules apply either.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, if you speak about the variable inside the thread function, only that function can access it (as always). If you mean the value of that variable, any code anywhere could access it and general rules about correct synchronization apply. It's not at all unusual to provide e.g. an event or mutex which is then shared. Actually, the answer to the OP's question is that since no special behaviour is documented, general rules apply, both general C rules and general POSIX thread rules.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special about pthread in this regard, so you'll not find a specific confirmation of this in the specs. from Open Group.

Your code is the only code that is going to de-reference the `arg` passed to pthread_create, you're responsible for its use and its lifetime.
At least this can be reasonably assumed by the virtue of the argument being a `void *`, which a pthread implementation wouldn't know how to safely dereference, and the documentation for pthread_create giving no indication that it would inspect the argument to the thread routine.

If you pass in a dynamically allocated object and use it after it's freed, or pass in a pointer to an object whose lifetime has ended, using that object is undefined behavior, otherwise there is not a problem. There's nothing specific about that regarding pthreads or the `arg` argument to pthread_create.

Comment: Small nit: a variable can't be freed. If it's a pointer (which it is in this case) and it points to an object with allocated storage, then *the object to which it points* can be freed.

Answer (score 0):

Freeing args, means that your program can use that memory location as it wants. Address of args was sent in thread function, meanwhile if your program doesn't touch that memory location(which means value is still there) you will have wanted behavior inside thread, if it does touch, you will have undefined. So overall, freeing args will produce undefined behavior.

Comment: Please fix your grammar.